# Recreating an object by calling its destructor and constructor explicitly

Tags: c++, c++17

I did not do something like this before and I am not sure if it is a bad practice or not. At least I do not see a reason why this code would not work:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    using Pair = std::pair<const std::string, int>;

    Pair p1("abc", 5);

    Pair p2;

    //Obviously this would not compile because the first pair element is const. The compiler error is:
    //Object of type 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted.
    //p2 = std::move(p1);

    //But there is a workaround.
    p2.~Pair();
    new (&p2) Pair(std::move(p1));

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a reason to avoid a code like this? Or what are the disadvantages of this code?

Comment: UB to access a new object created in the memory of a destructed object unless you call [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)

Comment: What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to assign to `p2`?

Comment: @RichardCritten what is wrong with the double destruction if it doubly created?

Comment: @AndyG How would you use `std::launder` here? The compiler stills calls the destructor of local object `p2`.

Comment: @andyg not any object, but I suspect this object.  Due to the const.

Comment: @AndyG I am trying to figure out what `std::launder` does.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky: Acts as an optimization barrier to force a load on a const object that previously may have been assumed not to change (which the compiler  may take advantage of to optimize away unnecessary loads)

Comment: **You should definitively avoid such code**. (1) If you declare it with **const**, there you should not modify it indirectly. People ready the code, might assume the value would not change (imagine a big application). (2) Explicit construction/destruction should generally be avoid in user code. Not everyone understand it and it is error-prone (for ex. what would happen if an exception is thrown between destruction and reconstruction). (3) If you work around the compiler, then it is usually a red-flag. In this case, you need to correct the declaration of `Pair` or not reuse p2.

Comment: I can only give an anectodal comment. I've seen this exact pattern in the code base of a large financial firm. Highly optimized low latency code base. The reason I recall is because it took the team months of debugging to figure out where the memory corruption was coming from. It broke either some compiler assumptions or some legitimate developer expectation. Just don't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the real problem is really simple. I am trying to implement a template function that reads a container elements from a stream and then inserts them to the container. Currently std::vector and std::map requires a separate implementations because std::map::value_type (that is std::pair<const Key, T> is not move-assignable).

Comment: If the constructor throws, then the already-destructed object `p2` will be automatically destructed again at the end of `main`, which is UB.

Comment: Even if this wasn't UB, you can't do the delete/placement new WA for an object stored in the map, since the new value probably will not be in the correct place in the tree.  There's a reason the key in a map is const.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm right, but I first declare a variable of type Container::value_type then read its value from the stream and then insert it to the container (Read function accepts it by reference: `void Read(value_type & val)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason to avoid a code like this? Or what are the disadvantages of this code?

You want to avoid this in general, and also especially if you are reusing a `const` type:

```
using Pair = std::pair<const std::string, int>;
```

In your specific case:

From [basic.life] (emphasis mine)

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and [...] a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
>   pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
>   object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be
>   used to manipulate the new object, if:
>      — the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, **does not contain any non-static
>   data member whose type is const-qualified** or a reference type

When a type is declared as `const`, the compiler is allowed to make assumptions that it won't change (because that's the contract that `const` gives us). And as a result is allowed to optimize away loads that appear later, meaning that *even if* if you reassign to it before you try to access it again, you may surprisingly still see the old value.

Your code exhibits undefined behavior because of the `const std::string` member of your `pair` instantiation. I've tested it in gcc, clang, and msvc, and they all appear to behave nicely in this specific case, but this is not guaranteed.

The proper way around this is use [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)(C++17), which acts as an optimization barrier that will force another load.

```
new (&p2) Pair(std::move(p1));
std::cout << std::launder(&p2)->first;
```

In general you want to avoid reusing storage unless you know exactly what you're doing because it is a minefield of undefined behavior.

Comment: You don’t have to use `launder` here—you can use the result of the `new` instead, since it unambiguously points to the new object.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this kind of behavior, see if you can use [std::optional](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/optional) instead.  It has to get all the hard cases correct.